# How do I create a sub class in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I am trying to create a subclass of a base class, but it does not seem to work.

I have the base class `Person` and a sub class `Student`, and the `Person` class is complete. Now I want to create a sub class `Student`. I have the following code:

```
namespace Uni
{
    class Student : public Person
    {
    private:
        int enrollNumber_;
        string majorCourse_;
        int averageGrade_;
        Student(const Student &);

    public:
        Student(int enrolled_number, string major_course, int average_grade);

        ~Student();

        const int getenrollNumber() const { return enrollNumber_; }
        const int getAverageGrade() const { return averageGrade_; }
        const string getMajorCourse() const { return majorCourse_;

    };

}
```

The problem is that the IDE says that on the line `class Student : Person` that `Person` [is] not a class or struct name.

How can I create the subclass `Student`?

Comment: Where is the class `Person` defined?  You should include the appropriate header.

Comment: `#include "Person.h"` probably.

Comment: Thanks @Nikos C. That helped